# How can i approach to reshape the data in desired format

Tags: python, pandas

Can anyone help me out on how to approach this problem

input DF

```
data = [['','x1','x2','x3','x4','x5' ],
    ['Date','p1','p2','p3','p4','p5'],
    ['10/24/2019',12,622,67,65,54],
    ['10/24/2019',298,387,162,38,38]] 
sample=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

output DF(desired):

```
index  Date      x_header P_header  Amount
   0 2019-10-24       x1       p1      12
   1 2019-10-24       x2       p2     622
   2 2019-10-24       x3       p3      67
   3 2019-10-24       x4       p4      65
   4 2019-10-24       x5       p5      54
   5 2019-10-25       x1       p1     298
   6 2019-10-25       x2       p2     387
   7 2019-10-25       x3       p3     162
   8 2019-10-25       x4       p4      38
   9 2019-10-25       x5       p5      38
```

I am  confused weather i have to melt,stack,unstack,transpose etc

Comment: @sshashank124 thank you for the quick advice. I have now editted my post

Comment: I was finally able to do if by using transpose first and then melt. This can be closed :)

Comment: Great! Please post your solution as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['','x1','x2','x3','x4','x5' ],
    ['Date','p1','p2','p3','p4','p5'],
    ['10/24/2019',12,622,67,65,54]
    ] 
sample=pd.DataFrame(data)
#Transposing the DF
df3=sample.transpose()
#grab the first row for the header
new_header = df3.iloc[0] 
#take the input less the header row
df3 = df3[1:] 
df3.columns = new_header

#Renaming X and P headers
df3.columns.values[0]='X_header'
df3.columns.values[1]='P_header'

#Melt the Frame now
df3=df3.melt(id_vars=['X_header','P_header'],var_name='date', value_name='amount')
```

Output:

```
     X_header P_header    date    amount
 0       x1       p1  10/24/2019     12
 1       x2       p2  10/24/2019    622
 2       x3       p3  10/24/2019     67
 3       x4       p4  10/24/2019     65
 4       x5       p5  10/24/2019     54
```